# GitHub Pages: 404 Error loading .csv file

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy a map online into GitHub pages, however I'm getting the error ([see webmap](https://cccruzr.github.io/maps/LideresSociales/)) which I'm not getting working locally:

```
GET https://cccruzr.github.io/maps/data/data.csv 404 (Not Found)
```

It is the first time that it happens to me since I've already uploaded other maps and webpages.

The line where I'm calling the file is the following (you can check the whole project -and file structure- on my [repository](https://github.com/cccruzr/LideresSociales/blob/0f029caa5633723f6b54fab94de4ecbfd7daa511/docs/js/d3_map.js#L95)):

```
var myLayer = omnivore.csv('../_data/data_lideres.csv', null, lideresLayer);
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

*NOTE: I was getting the same error with CSS files starting with underscore and had to rename all of them... it makes me think that it might be something related with Jekyll too...*

Comment: Your file doesn't exist, hence 404. Figure out how to upload it correctly.

Comment: That is exactly the reason of this question ;)

Comment: The starting slash of your url is probably a typo. Make sure you post code that reflects your error, or you will end up with irrelevant answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @ghybs reference [source](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=0oWMBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=javascript+The+Missing+Manual&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizierlrJbcAhUyq1kKHQL4B9wQ6AEIKDAA):

> When an external JavaScript file is loaded into a Web page, its frame of reference for document-relative paths is the location of the Web page itself. So, any document relative paths you include in the JavaScript file must be relative to the *Web page* and not the JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the url is missing the LideresSociales folder no? Maybe you're going back 1 folder more than needed in your code.

https://github.com/cccruzr/maps/blob/master/LideresSociales/data/data_lideres.csv

Try just `omnivore.csv('./data/data_lideres.csv', null, null);`

Comment: The root cause is very probably that OP made a url path relative to their JS file, whereas it should be relative to the HTML file that loads it. https://books.google.com/books?id=CxY3lNQTATQC&pg=PA471&lpg=PA471&dq=js+path+relative+page&source=bl&ots=E39WcaK0hn&sig=HXMKuFdbO7CO-lFm25IGHDbbAeE&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiewoKpt4ncAhVJcRQKHUiICK0Q6AEwCHoECAkQAQ (there should probably be some other resources easier to read).

Comment: @ghybs Thank you very much, you saved the day... I know it was such a silly mistake but I didn't know about the relative paths from .js files. Such a good lesson! *(Would you put your comment as an answer so I can accept it?)